# Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "class"

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to send an email with a token in order to resend an automated password. But in my view i'm retrieving the following error:

```
/**
     * @Route("/forget-email/", name="forget", methods="GET|POST")
     */
     public function emailrestore(Request $request, User $user, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
     {
        $url = "test";
        $form = $this->createForm(ForgetPasswordType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $email = $form['email']->getData();
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(User::class)
        ->find($email);
        if ( $email === $user ) {
            $mail = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
                ->setFrom('email@email.email')
                ->setTo($email)
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
                        'emails/registration.html.twig',array('url' => $url,)
                    ),
                    'text/html'
                );
                $mailer->send($mail);
        } else{
            var_dump("$email");
        }

        return $this->render('forget/email.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'error' => null,
        ]);
     }
```

Inside my entity i have email as unique

```
* @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
```

I'm retrieving the following error:
"Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "user"." Why?

Thanks for your explanation for advance

Comment: Solution here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530114/symfony-4-change-password-by-username-email-can-not-be-null

Answer (score 1):

You have "User $user" in your action parameter but you don't have a parameter 'user' in your request,  my guess is your ParamConverter can't convert this one into a User object because of that.

make your route a GET route formatted like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/forget-email/{user}", name="forget", methods="GET")
 */
```

Where user is whatever you want (mail, username, uid, etc ...) has long as it allows you tyo retrieve your user object and have your paramconverter converting it into a Doctrine object ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an initial value for your `$user` variable
Try this :

```
public function emailrestore(Request $request, User $user, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
```